What are the possible values for the cardinality of the continuum?
The continuum hypothesis says |C| = aleph-1.  We know that it can't be aleph-0.
Assuming the negation of the continuum hypothesis, |C| = aleph-n where n>1.  What are the possible values of n? And is n necessarily finite?
